# Connect to mySQL database, get random values of a certain column and store them into PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, database

Is there a better solution to store the data in this array **and**
why is the array empty or at least does not show?

I have this function that connets to a database, it works but I paste it in here for completeness. And to give a complete source (and with your answers a complete solution) for people who have the same problem.

**Funktion**

```
<?php
function OpenCon()
 {
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "user";
 $dbpass = "PetName[Birth:day]"; // ;) ;) 
 $db = "data";
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

 return $conn;
 }
```

**Then I run the funktion**

```
$conn = OpenCon();
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {}
```

**And here I try to store 400 random values of the column** `sent1` **from the table** `sent1`

```
$query = "SELECT sent1 FROM sent1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 400";
$result =  $conn->query($query);
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { array_push($sent1, $row["sent1"]);}
 print_r($sent1); echo $sent1[rand(0,399)];
```

btw. I found something interesting I want to share. In each and every answer I read, there was consent that `RAND()` is *very slow*.
In this case with a table of 120000 Rows, and 2 columns. If you want to get to get 400 random strings, `rand` is quicker than other solutions I tried. If you need only one, then there are certainly better solutions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is...

Comment: "why is the array empty or at least does not show?" seems to be the main part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the array before you can `array_push()` to it. Don't you get a warning from your code? I do in some short test code, keeps moaning that it needs an array and I've passed it null.

If you use `$sent1[] = $row["sent1"];` instead, it will automatically create the array, and seems to be considered quicker due to not having the overhead of calling a function.

If you're using PDO, you could use fetchAll() instead, to get all the result rows directly into an array. I'm not sure if there's a mysqli equivalent.

Comment: Implemented. Good I created a long thread for this :D :D

I ran it trough a validation tool and it did not show errors, the page also did not show errors even though 'ini_set('display_errors',"1")' was used. In 2 minutes I can reward this answer.